# Need some help regarding the family of $\mathbb{Z}_n = \lbrace 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n-1 \rbrace$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a couple of questions about some problems in my discrete mathematics text Discrete Mathmatical Structures 6th Edition, on page 467-468 they are as follows.

Each member of the family $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has two operations defined as follows:

$a \oplus _n b = a + b (mod n)$ & $a \otimes_n b = ab (mod n)$

The result of each operation mod $n$ must be a number between $0$ and $n - 1$ (inclusive), so to satisfy the closure property for each operation we restrict the objects in the structure based on mod n to $0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1$.  Let $\mathbb{Z}_n = (\lbrace0, 1, 2, 3, ...., n-1\rbrace, \oplus_n, \otimes_n).$

Part 3: Here you will develop some general conclusions about the family of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

1: Let $a ∈ \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $a \neq 0$. Tell how to compute -a using n and a.

2: For which positive integers k does $a \otimes_k x = 1$ have a unique solution for each a, 0 < a < k -1?

3: For which positive integers k does $a \otimes_k x = 1$ not have a unique solution for each a, 0 < a < k -1?

For the first question  I had no idea how to proceed. However, a friend asked a professor who said the answer was $-a = an - a[n+1]$, I would like to understand the process of how they came to that answer.

For the second two answers I am confused on what the text is asking for and what I need to do to find the answer. These operations were never covered in the text. I've tried just picking an $a$ and a $k$ and then proceed to solve for $x$ but I get stuck because I don't know how to remove a $(mod)$ function algebraically.

Comment: Have you tried doing the first by hand for small $n$?  $n=5$ is a good choice.  There aren't many to choose from there and you may notice a pattern.  What is $\otimes_k$?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ is a group, modulo $n$, under addition modulo n?

Comment: $a \otimes_k x$ is (a * x) mod k
What method would you even use to calculate -a  using n and a?

Comment: @Ada: add $n{} {} {} {} $.

Comment: @Berci: add $n$ to what?   $-a = ??? + n$ my text doesn't give an equation or anything.

Comment: How is addition defined on $\{0,1, \dots n-1\}$? What is $a\ +\ (n-a)$?

Comment: @Berci Sorry, I'm not really sure. I'm new to this subject should the problem have defined that?

Comment: Yes, it should have defined it.

Comment: I just got the answer for part 1 from a friend who asked a professor it's apparently $-a = an - a[n+1]$. However, I have no idea how they got it.

Comment: Note that "my discrete mathematics text" could very well be different for every user that reads your question. Please specify exactly which text it is, which page, and state its definitions of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and what exactly it means by "$-a$".

Answer (score 0):

For part 1, notice that what you need to do is essentially break $\mathbb{Z}$ into sets of length $n$, starting from 0, and going in both directions. Then, notice that for some $a$, you can get a nice relation for $-a$ as well, think of it as finding the position of $-a$ in this set of $n$ elements. You might also just use the addition operation and use the fact that $-a$ is the additive inverse of $a$.

For part 2, I am not very sure about what you mean. Suppose that $k|(ax-1)$. If $x_0$ is a solution to this, note that $x_i=x_0+ik, i\in \mathbb{Z}$ also satisfies your equation. I believe there must be some restrictions on $x$ as well?

Comment: Part 1 I just got the answer from a friend its apparently -a = an -a[n+1]. However, i'll have to figure out exactly how they got that.

Part 2 I'm just as confused on what it means. Exact wording in the text is - 

     "For which positive integers $k$ does $a \otimes_n x =1$ have a unique solution for each $a$ , $0 < a < k-1$?"

Comment: Erm, I'm not really sure if that's the answer you should be looking at. If you're not sure about what I mean by the first part, draw the integers on the number line, and divide them into sets of $k$ consecutive ones (say $k=5$ as suggested) with one end at 0. Take the two groups close to $0$, $A=\mathbb{Z}\Cap[-k,0)$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}\Cap[0,k)$. Their elements are then $\{-k, -k+1,\ldots, -1\}$ and $\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$. Since the idea of taking $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is identical to listing out the remainders corresponding to each integer, for your purposes, $-k$ & $0$ are identical. Now find $-a$.